# Force an object to be called via its interface

Tags: c#, oop, interface

How can I force an object to be called only via its interface? That can only accomplish via Access Modifier but in C# can't do.

I have:

```
public interface IProfile { string GetName(); }
public class Profile : IProfile { 
    public string GetName() { return "Linh"; }
}
```

I have a code section like that above. I put it in a class library after that I generate an assembly.

In a web project some programmers will add reference to that assembly. If they want to call Profile class then they must use IProfile interface as declaration below:

```
IProfile ip = new Profile(); 
ip.GetName();
```

But some careless programmers won't do so. They will use below way:

```
Profile pr = new Profile(); 
pr.GetName();
```

Comment: I write a class library and programmers will call some objects in that via object's interface. But I think that can't accomplish in C#

Comment: Linh: Please write a pseudo-code version of what you want to do. It's not very clear.

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: Are you asking for explicit interface implementation, i.e. specifying that a method can only be called via an interface reference, not a class reference?  Or about making a whole class internal but exposing instances as an interface type?

Comment: public interface IProfile
{
    string GetName();
}

public class Profile : IProfile
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Linh";
    }
}

I have a code section above. I put it in a class library after that I generate an assembly. In a web project some programmers will add reference to that assembly. If they want to call Profile class then they must use IProfile interface as declaration below:

IProfile ip = new Profile();
ip.GetName();

But some careless programmers won't do so. They will use below way:

Profile pr = new Profile();
pr.GetName();

Comment: Thank itowlson. You understood my problem

Comment: @Linh: edit your question to add that code. A comment isn't the place for that. Do you know how to edit your question?

Comment: @Linh: The relevant section of the specification is §13.4 (Interface implementations) especially §13.4.1 (Explicit interface member implementations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really simple. Use an explicit interface implementation:

```
public interface IProfile { string GetName(); }
public class Profile : IProfile
{
    string IProfile.GetName() { return "Linh"; }
}
```

`GetName` can now only be called through an interface reference.

Comment: True :-(. Is there no way users with sufficient rep can just accept an answer? Perhaps we should have a 'secondary' accepted answer feature (which anyone with sufficient rep can mark) which will automatically become accepted after maybe a month, if the question poster does not care to mark one.

Comment: I am a very tolerant guy but this person seems to ignore all reminders to accept an answer. They seem to have a decent grasp of English so what is their excuse?

Comment: @Moron: I don't think so, because it still allows someone to get an instance of the `Profile` class, which is the real issue (as I see it).

Comment: @Silky: See comments by Linh in the question. He/She did not want IProfile ip = new Profile(); misused as Profile p = new Profile().

Comment: @Moron: it's not the instance that's the issue. The OP doesn't want the method called directly through the instance. He wants to require the method be called through the interface.

Comment: Wow, I actually did not know this until just now.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to adopt a factory approach, like so:

```
using System;

using Ext;

namespace ConsoleApplication26
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IFoo foo = FooFactory.GetFoo();
        }
    }
}


// another project/dll

namespace Ext
{
    public interface IFoo
    {
        void M ();
    }


    public static class FooFactory
    {
        public static IFoo GetFoo ()
        {
            return new Foo();
        }
    }


    class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public void M () { }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Silky: how does this prevent method M from being called directly?

Comment: You should probably protect the constructor for Foo, so that only other classes in the module can access it. (I am not a C# programmer so I don't know what the appropriate access level for this is.) EDIT: whoops, didn't see that there is no "public" modifier on the Foo class.

Comment: John: Re his comment, I inferred that he wanted people to not specify the type on the left hand side (Maybe I misunderstood). The only way to do this is to not give access to the underlying type at all (as per a factory). His subject title was pretty misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If the question meant to be "How to force calling of interfaced methods only ?", then the answer could be: "Make the rest of methods private"